# PrimeFaces theme does not apply in JSF with Maven

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I just want to change the theme of my Application but it does not work.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

I use Maven to get the libraries and have the following both dependencies which should be enough or not?
pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>6.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't know if you need more informations like an example .xhtml of my Application or something.

Edit: I know it's recommended to post only necessary code but I don't know which parts are needed right now. That's the xhtml for my search:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" 
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:composition template="layout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="eintraegeSuche">
            <p:panel header="Telefonbucheinträge durchsuchen">
            <p:dataTable id="table" var="telefonbuch" value="#{sucheController.eintraege}" stickyHeader="true" resizableColumns="true" liveResize="true" style="margin-bottom:20px" paginator="true" rows="10" emptyMessage="Keine Telefonbucheinträge vorhanden" selection="#{telefonbuchList.selectedEntries}" selectionMode="multiple" rowKey="#{telefonbuch.id}"
                paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:commandButton id="toggler" type="button" value="Anzeige" style="float:right" icon="pi pi-align-justify" />
                    <p:columnToggler datasource="table" trigger="toggler" />    
                </f:facet>
                    <p:column sortBy="#{telefonbuch.vorname}">
                        <f:facet name="header">Vorname</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{telefonbuch.vorname}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column sortBy="#{telefonbuch.nachname}">
                        <f:facet name="header">Nachname</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{telefonbuch.nachname}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column sortBy="#{telefonbuch.telefonnummer}">
                        <f:facet name="header">Telefonnummer</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{telefonbuch.telefonnummer}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column sortBy="#{telefonbuch.handynummer}">
                        <f:facet name="header">Handynummer</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{telefonbuch.handynummer}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column sortBy="#{telefonbuch.geschaeftsstelle}">
                        <f:facet name="header">Geschäftsstelle</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{telefonbuch.geschaeftsstelle}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="7">
                    <p:outputLabel for="vorname" value="Vorname: " />
                    <p:inputText id="vorname" value="#{sucheController.telefonbuch.vorname}" />
                    <p:outputLabel for="nachname" value="Nachname: " />
                    <p:inputText id="nachname" value="#{sucheController.telefonbuch.nachname}" />
                    <p:outputLabel for="vorname" value="Telefonnummer: " />
                    <p:inputText id="telefonnummer" value="#{sucheController.telefonbuch.telefonnummer}" />
                    <p:outputLabel for="vorname" value="Handynummer: " />
                    <p:inputText id="handynummer" value="#{sucheController.telefonbuch.handynummer}" />
                    <p:outputLabel for="geschaeftsstelle" value="Geschäftsstelle: " />
                    <p:inputText id="geschaeftsstelle" value="#{sucheController.telefonbuch.geschaeftsstelle}" />
                    <h:commandButton value="Suchen" update="table" action="#{sucheController.search(sucheController.telefonbuch.vorname, sucheController.telefonbuch.nachname, sucheController.telefonbuch.telefonnummer, sucheController.telefonbuch.handynummer, sucheController.telefonbuch.geschaeftsstelle)}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: So it works when you manually add the themes jar to your project and not via maven? (there is a 1.0.10 theme jar btw)

Comment: I guess you have completely discarded a Browser caching issue.. Then it might be handy to have your sample xhtml file.

Comment: @Kukeltje didn't tried it yet. When i try to add the 1.0.10 theme in my pom it's crying missing artifact. As well when I don't use .extension and use .themes.

Comment: @XtremeBiker added some xhtml

Comment: Example xhtml, if relevant, should be in [mcve] flavour. And https://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/all-themes/1.0.10/ is present... So fix your local problem! (and there is no (old) 1.0.8 anymore)

Comment: @Kukeltje seems a bit unfixable. Whatever I do and try the artifact is missing. Already tried 5 solutions from StackOverflow

Comment: @Kukeltje okay i fixed it and got now the newest version of primefaces themes. I had to add the repository of PrimeFaces. But still it does not apply the theme with the contextParam

Comment: Please, try with a xhtml in its simplest form, as @Kukeltje points out. You can use the simplest one from the PF site in its 'getting started' area. Also it is recommended to do the mappings with xhtml suffix in jsf 2.x

Comment: And there are multiple Q/A on this in SO

Comment: I tried it now with the short getting started webpage from PrimeFaces. I also downloaded the afterdark-1.0.10.jar theme and added it manually to the buildpath and set the context param to this value. Not even this does work. Not theme is applied. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score -3):

It may be a little late, but I had the same issue. Once I embedded the <p:dataTable> in a `<h:body>` tag, the theme was applied. Otherwise, the table was really ugly without styling.

```
<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable ...>
            ...
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Sorry if my answer does not seem is late and looked irrelevant... But ensuring using `<h:body>` instead of `<body>` in the JSF fixed the issue with the PrimeFaces CSS. I thought it could be your case too. Care to explain the downvotes please?